# Laptop Battery Life increased in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, laptop, battery

I own a Dell Inspiron 15R laptop (Intel i5 @2.5GHz, 4GB RAM, 750GB HDD 7200rpm, 15.6inch display, Bluetooth, WiFi, etc) which is my primary machine for both work and personal use.

I made a clean installation with 14.04 64-bit and I have noticed that my battery GAIN 1.5hour battery life (total 3.5hours) with this new Ubuntu release compared with 12.04 64bit with the same use!!

I really don't have any problem with that, actually I am thrilled, but I wonder why this is happening...

Note that I did NOT installed any extra packages such as laptop tools, tlp, etc just clean Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

Any ideas why is this happening...???

Comment: New kernel. Most likely.

Comment: - the new kernel has "laptop-tools" enabled. That got included in between 12.04 and 14.04.

Comment: I can understand that kernel and "laptop tools" have significant role for this. But it is 1.5hour MORE that it was before...! :) I think it is weird...

Comment: actully I am also using i5 quad core processor and 6 GB RAM with 1TB HDD and compared to windows the battery life is decreased....but as everything comes with price this is the price of using fast ever safe and awesome ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an Nvidia/AMD graphics card? Since Ubuntu 14.04, the Linux kernel by default supports dynamic power management for open source drivers, which wasn't there before. It will improve battery life, reduce fan speed, and reduce laptop temperature by dynamically switching between two graphics cards when needed.

Also a lot of tweaks were added to support better battery life.